# Loop through subscribed and unsubscribed users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, if-statement

I have a problem with a Twilio app that I'm building. Right now I have an option for a user to be 'unsubscribed' but they still receive a message if they are. It makes sense that they do I just can't figure out how to change it. I tried a if else statment in the method that I will include in the bottom of this question. Is their a way I can loop through unsubscribed and subscribed with a if else?

```
def send_message(msg)
  if Person.subscribed == true
    @twilio_number = ENV["TWILIO_NUMBER"]
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"], ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]

    @client.account.messages.create(
      from: @twilio_number,
      to: phone_number,
      body: msg
    )
  end
end
```

Right now if one person is unsubscribed it sends to nobody I just want it to send to subscribed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through all `Person` objects:

```
Person.find_each do |person|
  if person.subscribed
    # code here
  else
    # code here
  end
end
```

P.S.

Note, that default solution would be to use `each` to iterate through ActiveRecord objects, but I strongly recommend to use `find_each`, because it will load records in the memory in batches (10000 is the default batch size), whereas `each` would load all records at once.

[More info](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each)